# Cast a variable from one Type to another extended Type

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have

```
interface Type1 {
   id: number;
}

interface Type2 extends Type1 {
   name: string;
}

const type1: Type1 = {id: 123};
```

Now I want to create `type2` from `type1` and add the `name` to it. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The safest way is to use spread:

```
interface Type1 {
id: number;
}

interface Type2 extends Type1 {
name: string;
}

const type1: Type1 = {id: 123};
const type2: Type2 = { ...type1, name: "bob"};
```

You can also use `Object.assign`, but you loose excess property checks. On the other hand you can use the same object instance if you want:

```
const type2: Type2 = Object.assign(type1, { name: "bob"}); // we assign to the object in  type1, so we are adding to that object.

const type2: Type2 = Object.assign({}, type1,{ name: "bob"}); // or we assign to a new object.
```

You can also use a type assertion, but the object will be in an invalid type  state until you assign `name`:

```
const type2: Type2 = type1 as Type2; // type2 is in an invalid state as name is not assigned
type2.name = "bob"
```